# How can I return extra columns (like ItemType & WebDAV Folder) when using GetSearchResults() for an IdentifiableObject

Tags: 2011, core-service

I used the code sample below to return a list of recently-modified items from the Core Service.  `GetSearchResults()` returns an array of IdentifiableObjectData's.

Can I include extra columns in the search results?

For the moment I'm looking for ItemType & WebDAV folder.

```
        LinkToIdentifiableObjectData folder = new LinkToIdentifiableObjectData();
        folder.IdRef="tcm:1-1-2";
        filter.SearchIn = folder;
        filter.ModifiedAfter = Convert.ToDateTime("03/01/13");
        var results = client.GetSearchResults(filter);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The WebDavURL is available in the LocationInfo property. You must cast the item to RepositoryLocalObject first, e.g.:

```
string webdavUrl = ((RepositoryLocalObjectData) item).LocationInfo.WebDavUrl;
```

However, I'm not sure if this property is filled when you search. It could be that you need to read the IdentifiableObjectData separately for each item in the results.

To get to the item type, you can either parse the Id yourself (it is a TcmUri presented as a string), or check if the item is of a certain type, e.g.:

```
if (item is ComponentData) { // action goes here }
```